# Controling number of spaces per tab character in openoffice

Tags: printing, openoffice

I want to print a program file from OpenOffice Writer, so I use a mono font and adjust size and margins to my liking.

The indentation in the program file is based on tab characters, so I would like to adjust the number of printed spaces per tab character, how can I do that? By default it's outputting 7 spaces per tab character for some reason. My version is 3.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting fixed tabstops, you may be better off by simply doing a **find / replace using regular expressions: In the `search for` textbox (1), enter `\t`; in the `Replace with` textbox (2), enter four spaces (for example)**. While using a monospaced font, this will create indentation as expected. Make sure to select the `Regular expressions` option from `Other options`(3)

[image: Search for tabs, replace with spaces]

Additionally, one of the different extensions to highlight code (**[coooder](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/coooder)** [LibreOffice], **[Code Colorizer](http://extensions.openoffice.org/de/project/code-colorizer)** [OpenOffice]) may be useful.

### EDIT:

To adapt the tabs for program code files, you need to **modify the `Preformatted Text` paragraph style in your default template**. But take care that **there's no way to set the tabs to a certain amount of characters**. If you want to keep the tabs, you will have to check the width of a monospaced character of your favourite monospaced font, and set the tabs for the `Preformatted Text` paragraph style accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing this already, I was looking for a way to cut out this step, just open a file and print it.

Comment: AFAIS there's no way to do so - see my edited answer.